# React.js how do i show pages depending on the status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement a case where when users are logged in that they need to able to access the AppStack and the AuthStack. And if they not logged in, only the AuthStack will be accessible. Also when they try to access the AppStack they should get redirected. In react native I could handle this with a AuthStack and if something changed the user status he could see the one stack or the other one. But I don't know how to do it with reactjs

AuthNavigator

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import app from './firebase';
import AuthStack from './stacks/AuthStack';
import AppStack from './stacks/AppStack';

function AuthNavigator() {
  const [initializing, setInitializating] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(true);

  function onAuthStateChanged(result) {
    setUser(result);
    if (initializing) setInitializating(false);
    if (result) {
      app
        .auth()
        .currentUser.getIdToken(/* force Refresh */ true)
        .then((idToken) => {
          result.idToken = idToken;
          setUser(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const authSubscriber = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return authSubscriber;
  });

  if (initializing) {
    return null;
  }
  return user ? <AppStack user={user} /> : <AuthStack user={user} />;
}
export default AuthNavigator;
```

AppStack here i tried it like if there is a user then you can render the appStack else you get redirected to the authstack.

```html
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Overview from '../pages/app/Overview';
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar/Sidebar';

function AppStack({ user }) {
  return this.props.user ? (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Sidebar user={user} />
        <Route path="/app-melior/overview" exact component={Overview}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  ) : (
    <Redirect path="/auth/signin"></Redirect>
  );
}

export default AppStack;
```

AuthStack

```html
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from '../pages/auth/SignIn';
function AuthStack({ user, app }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth">
            <Navbar />
            <Route path="/auth/signin" app={app} exact component={SignIn} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default AuthStack;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a Private route and hanlde it like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import app from './firebase';
import AuthStack from './stacks/AuthStack';
import AppStack from './stacks/AppStack';


function AuthNavigator() {
  const [initializing, setInitializating] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(true);

  const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        user ? (
          <Component {...props}></Component>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/auth"></Redirect>
        )
      }
      ></Route>
    );
  };

  function onAuthStateChanged(result) {
    setUser(result);
    if (initializing) setInitializating(false);
    if (result) {
      app
        .auth()
        .currentUser.getIdToken(/* force Refresh */ true)
        .then((idToken) => {
          result.idToken = idToken;
          setUser(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const authSubscriber = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return authSubscriber;
  });

  if (initializing) {
    return null;
  }
  return    
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/app>
            <Sidebar user={user} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app-melior/overview" exact component={Overview}></PrivateRoute>
        </PrivateRoute>

        <Route path="/auth">
            <Navbar />
            <Route path="/auth/signin" app={app} exact component={SignIn} />
         </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>;
}
export default AuthNavigator;
```